# Custom selected tab colour in new android.support.design.widget.TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I would like to know that is it possible to change selected tab colour in new design tablayout? I found the solution for selected tab text color but I would like to know to change tab colour itself.

[image]

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/TabLayout.Theme"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</RelativeLayout>





<style name="TabLayout.Theme" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
        <item    name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Jacksonville.Tab</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/text_dim</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@color/color_heading</item>
    </style>
```

i need to change selected tab colour like this.

Comment: Please add more details to the question, as it is not explicitly clear.

Comment: please check i added tab image.

Comment: It would be good if you add relevant code as well :)

Comment: please check  the code

Answer (score 2):

you just need to set `app:tabBackground` attribute

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_color"
```

and create a drawable file as `tab_selector_color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

so The complete xml code will be look like

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/mainBlue"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi  you can make the hight of the indicator to equal the height of the tablayout so the indicator will cover the all size of the selected item in tab layout

```
 <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">

        <!-- the color you want in selected tab -->
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#50000000</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>

           <!-- set the indicator hieght equal to tablayout height -->
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">60dp</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#222222</item>
```